# MaskedEdit extender issue in IE9

Tags: asp.net-ajax

[image]

In my page i have a textbox for diplay date with Ajax Masked edit extender control but when i open the page getting an error like "Unspecified JavaScript Error" but it's works good in IE7,8 not IE9 and also working on Safari.
Below is my code sample:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReturnedDate" CssClass="calendarField" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtReturnedDate"  PopupButtonID="imgReturnedDate" 
                                              PopupPosition="Right" CssClass="Calendar"/>
                        <asp:linkbutton runat="server" CssClass="calendarButton" ID="imgReturnedDate" Text="<img border='0' class='calendarButton' src='Images/coreCalendarIcon.gif'>"></asp:linkbutton> 
                        <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtReturnedDate" Mask="99/99/9999" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" AutoComplete="false" 
                            OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" MaskType="Date" DisplayMoney="None" AcceptNegative="None"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a master page drop the following in the < head>

< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=7" />

This will tell the browser to use IE8 Standards vs IE9